# Display diffForHumans in Carbon with custom time?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have a value in my database of `156858` which holds the online time for a user. At the moment I'm displaying it in days and hours like below...

```
{{ $d = floor($user->userStats->OnlineTime /86400) }} days, 
{{ floor(($user->userStats->OnlineTime -$d*86400)/3600) }} hours
```

It current outputs

```
1 days, 19 hours
```

I'm trying to use Carbon to do a diffForHumans string so it outputs something like `1 day, 19 hours, and 24 minutes` but it doesn't seem that Carbon has this functionality?

Is there any other way I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `parse()` method like this:

```
{{ Carbon::parse('-' . $user->userStats->OnlineTime . ' minutes')->diffForHumans() }}
```

But a better way is to [keep all dates as `dateTime()` in DB](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#store-dates-in-the-standard-format-use-accessors-and-mutators-to-modify-date-format) as I'm showing in my repo. In this case, you could just do this:

```
{{ $user->userStats->OnlineTime->diffForHumans() }}
```